# when i send message from my web application to phone

Tags: php, mysqli

/*facing this problem */
     when I send message from my web application to phone 
    like as "HI Naveed your 
    task id is '$task_id'";then i received on phone like 
    "HI Naveed your task is  & # 039; 67 & # 039;"".How i can remove it??

Answer (score 0):

**write like this:**

```
"HI Naveed your 
task id is".$task_id;
```